# Java regex to extract filename from multipart field not working

Tags: java, android, regex, multipart

I am using the following regex to extract the filename from an rfc822 multipart email.

```
private static Pattern filenamePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=filename=\").*?(?=\")");
```

This is able to extract filenames that have a space, as in:

```
Content-Type : application/pdf; name="Key.Enrollment_Final.pdf"
```

but cannot extract filenames that are not quoted, like:

```
Content-Type : application/octet-stream;    name=.config
```

I cannot quite figure out how to get both. For the first quote, I think I can check for (?<=filename=\"?), but how should I check for a space or an end of line or a quote?

Comment: How are you even able to get the file name in the first case? It shouldn't even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only seen `filename` attribute being specified in `Content-Disposition` header, but not `Content-Type` header.

Either way, this is a regex that correctly matches `filename` attribute, according to [RFC 1806](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1806) (which references [RFC 1521](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521) and [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822).

```
"filename=(?:([\\x21-\\x7E&&[^\\Q()<>[]@,;:\\\"/?=\\E]]++)|\"((?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[\t ])+|[^\r\"\\\\]|\\\\[\\x00-\\x7f])*)\")"
```

Well, matching is one thing, but you still have to process the file name in the second case, at least to unquote special characters. (You still need to collapse linear-white-space: `(?:(?:\r\n)?[\t ])+`, as defined in RFC 822, to a single space, and replace non-printable characters).

Comment: Yep, it was Content-Disposition. I copied the body and headers seperately and messed up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern works on both of your test cases above. Group 1 contains your filename.

```
name=\"?(.*)\"?
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood it correctly, but if you want to keep just the name of the file, this should work:

```
private static Pattern filenamePattern = Pattern.compile(".*application\\/.* name=\\"?([^ ]+)\\"?");
```

In `filenamePattern.match(1)` you should have the result

Answer (score 0):

I guess this Regex would serve your purpose:

```
name\=\"?([\w\.]+)\"?
```

You can work on the `([\w\.]+)` according to your file names, but the current state catches the two given examples.

[Check this Regex101 fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/iU3pI5)